# Active font color Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am using a worksheet (Excel 2010) on monthly basis and want to use red colour instead of default black. I don't want to change Excel template as I only use red colour for the spreadsheet. At the moment every time I change cell value I need to change font colour again and again as default is black. I read all the tips online and couldn't find any help.

Comment: try to change it in font settings. Because there is default font, so just color for default font... i tried it in 07excel, but maybe it will help in excel 2010 (even in your strange 20160 version :p )

Comment: Even though colour is changed to red in Font Settings every time I change value in a cell the colour of entered data is black again.

Comment: Could you not clone the template you are using and have 2, with variations where you need them?

Comment: I did. I opened my RedFontTemplate and first cell I entered value was red font colour but every next after first one was in black font colour. It's like whenever I change focus from one cell to another the font colour goes back to black again.

Comment: I found out that it happens as font colour is predetermined. So cells already are in black as default till I change them. Is there any way I can change Font Colour on "Enter" press button via VBA or similar solution?

Comment: Yes there is way via VBA, but first can you check if you already have some macro here? Becaouse your behaviour seems strange

Comment: It happens on every workbook I open even new ones without macros.

Comment: Any VBA code or other solutions anyone?